When did Kritavarma switch sides?
When Krishna came to Hastinapura to broker a peace-deal, Satyaki and Kritavarma came along with him.

Satyaki and Kritavarman and the other mighty car-warriors of the Vrishni race, all rode behind Krishna on cars and steeds and elephants. [Udhyoga Parva; SECTION XCIV  05,092.001]

Kritavarma was also there when Duryodhana planned to arrest Krishna; Kritavarma prepared his men for battle while Satyaki went to inform Krishna about Duryodhana's plans.
Before this, when all the kings and warriors assembled in Upaplavya, I did not come across Kritavarma's name.
When the battle starts, Kritavarma was on Kauravas side.
Now, was Kritavarma at Upaplavya till the war broke out (during preparations, peace offerings, etc.) and then moved to Kuru camp? OR, did he just accompany Krishna to Hastinapura?

Kritavarma had already promised to Join Duryodhana even before Krishna's peace mission to Hastinapura. It was When Duryodhana and Arjuna had come to Dwaraka seeking Krishna's help and Duryodhana obtained the Narayani Sena. After that Duryodhana had went to Kritavarma who promised to help him.

"And the royal son of Dhritarashtra then went to Kritavarman. And
Kritavarman gave him a body of troops numbering an Akshauhini. And
surrounded by that military host, terrible to behold, the Kaurava
marched forth delighting his friends."


Chapter VII, Udyoga Parva, Mahabharata.


Yes, but why then he was coming from Upaplavya to Hastinapura, and then returned back to Upaplavya with Krishna...Pandavas had enemy sitting in their camp and listening to all the planning? Can't be. After the agreements in Dwarka, there was no mention of him with Pandavas to Krishna's travel.

@Kanthri - He is obliged to join the Kauravas only when the war starts. He didn't join any Pandava meeting. He only accompanied Krishna in the peace mission.

If Kritavevrma wanted to protect Krishna from Dhuryodhana, then offering him his support doesn't sound right. Him being with Pandavas and on the day of the war going and standing on other side also doesn't look right. As Mahabharata doesn't explain why he was with Krishna, it's probably difficult to answer my question.

@Kanthri He was not with Pandavas from beginning.. "And Kritavarman, the son of Hridika, accompanied by the Bhojas, the Andhas, and the Kukuras, came to Duryodhana with an Akshauhini of troops" ~ MBH.05.19.. He along with other Yadava warriors was just in protection of Krishna (MBH.5.94)..actually, it's confusing but you can also argue if Krishan wants Pandavas to win then why he gave his some army to Duryodhana..same way for all Yadava warriors Krishna was first but he himself promised portion of army to Duryodhana so few had to fought from that side..
